# Collection initializer for List<myCustomClass> not working giving "; expected" compile error. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, compiler-errors, initializer

I am trying to initialize a generic collection List something like this:

```
List<MyCustomClass> myCustomClassList = new List<MyCustomClass>() {myCustomClassInstance1, myCustomClassInstance2};
```

I am getting the compile error "*; expected*". I don't understand this. Shouldn't I just be able to initialize this collection like this?

Comment: Sure.  How old is your Visual Studio edition?

Comment: I'm using .NET 2.0 with VS 2005. Guess that's my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of .NET are you using? Collection initializers only work in .NET 3.5 and higher

Comment: I'm using .NET 2.0 with VS 2005.

Comment: Yeppers, that is your problem, you need VS2008 or higher for collection initializers

Comment: Ok. I have used array (non-generic) initializers, so those work, just not the collection initializers I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Collection Initializers are part of the C# 3.0 specification and not the .Net Framework/Libraries. The earliest implementation that uses C# 3.0 is VS2008, and the .Net 3.5 framework. You can build against earlier versions of the framework.  If you are compiling via script from the command-line, or other IDE, make sure you are referencing the appropriate toolchain: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe